# Flask not being able to read image uploaded from html

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to make a simple html webpage where a user can upload an image. This image is passed on to a flask API through a form wherein the image is passed to an image classification model. However, I am not able to recieve the image in the Flask API after I upload the file. I get an error saying
`werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'uploaded_img'` 
Can anyone guide me where I am going wrong?

My html code:

```
<body class="center-screen">
    <div id="content">
        <form id="url-form" action="/classify_image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1>Upload Image</h1>
            <div class="formcontainer">
                <hr/>
                <div class="container">
                    <label for="img">Upload image:</label>
                    <input type="file" id="img" name="uploaded_img" accept="image/*">
                </div>
                <button type="submit">
                    <strong>Classify Image</strong>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

My flask endpoint:

```
@app.route('/classify_image', methods=['POST'])
def classify_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Running")
        f = request.files['uploaded_img']
        model.predict(f)
```

Comment: Can you print the value of f and write here?

Comment: Actually f isn't even printed. It throws the error I mentioned before that line runs

Comment: comment that request.file['uploaded_img'] line and try again.

Comment: If I comment that line, how am I going to access the image file then? The endpoint works fine btw as "Running" gets printed. Problem is with the request.files['uploaded_img'] line

Comment: oh sorry 
get the value of request.files only